How to update version in emulator package.xml
I downgraded emulator and copied package.xml from previous emulator to downloaded emulator. I tried to change the version in xml file by opening the file. I couldn’t update. Please suggest how to update. Thank your
I opened xml and tried to update.

hi, i want to follow you on instagram : )

It sounds like you need to update the version in your package.xml file for an emulator after downgrading it. Here's a step-by-step guide to help you achieve this:

Locate the package.xml File:

Find the directory where your emulator is installed. The package.xml file should be in the root directory of the emulator installation.


Open the package.xml File:

Use a text editor (like Notepad, VSCode, or any XML editor) to open the package.xml file.


Modify the Version:

Look for the version tag within the XML file. It might look something like this:
<package>
    <revision>
        <major>XX</major>
        <minor>XX</minor>
        <micro>XX</micro>
    </revision>
</package>


Change the values inside the <major>, <minor>, and <micro> tags to match the version you want to set.


Save the File:

After making the necessary changes, save the file.


Verify the Changes:

Open the emulator or the tool that uses this emulator and verify if it reflects the updated version.



Example:
If the original package.xml had:
<package>
    <revision>
        <major>30</major>
        <minor>1</minor>
        <micro>0</micro>
    </revision>
</package>
And you want to change it to version 29.3.2, you would update it to:
<package>
    <revision>
        <major>29</major>
        <minor>3</minor>
        <micro>2</micro>
    </revision>
</package>

